# Problem with GWT App can't get HTTP Response back from Servlet on another server

Tags: java, http, gwt, servlets

I have Application written with GWT 1.7. I have one page where I upload file to the remote server that is on different domain. So, when I do Post to the server files goes to the server but when it's time to get response I'm getting null in following function:

Servlet:

```
...
resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_CREATED);
resp.getWriter().print("The file was created successfully.");
resp.flushBuffer();
...
```

GWT:

```
form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler() {
            public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
                Window.alert(event.getResults());
            }
```

Javadoc for event.getResults() said following:

> Returns: the result html, or null if
>   there was an error reading it @tip The
>   result html can be null as a result of
>   submitting a form to a different
>   domain.

[This is the code example](http://code.google.com/p/faculty-gwt/source/browse/#svn/trunk/examples/gwtfileupload) that I tried to follow. It works as is, but when I'm calling my servlet the response is null.

By the way I tried to use Firebug to see Headers and it seems to me that servlet is sending response back. I think it's just GWT does not like it. Is there any work around for this so I can get my response in GWT?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not to state the obvious but it says right in the quote you posted what is wrong:

> The result html can be null as a result of submitting a form to a different domain.

It looks like the code sample you link to is on the same domain so it's not violating the same origin policy for the browser.

There's [this workaround](http://timepedia.blogspot.com/2008/07/cross-domain-formpanel-submissions-in.html)  but it seems to be for earlier version of GWT and only works for Firefox.

Comment: So, there is no way of getting response from the remote server? Is there any other technologies/techniques I can use to get that message from the server?

Comment: You could use a JS library (or something you write) that dynamically inserts a script tag.  Here's an article about it: http://jaybyjayfresh.com/2007/09/17/using-script-tags-to-do-remote-http-calls-in-javascript/  Most of the major JS libs do this out of the box.  Not 100% sure how you would incorporate it into GWT though.